# What repository is a yum group sourced from?

Tags: linux, yum, rhel7

Is there an easy way to determine where a specific yum group is sourced?

I can query what groups are available using `yum grouplist`.
I can query group information using `yum group info $yum_group_name`

What's troubling me is I can't determine which repository a group is being sourced from.

The best I've done is find what repositories hold the group:

```
yum_group_name="....."  # or ID 
# find all repository identifiers
# perform yum commands with only 1 repository enabled
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/*  | grep '\[.*\]' | grep -v '#' | tr -d '[]' | xargs -I {} -t sh -c "yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='{}' group info $yum_group_name 2>&1 | grep 'Group:'"
# subsequently, associate a bareurl to repository identifier
```

Say a group exists in multiple repositories, how do I know which one is used?

Comment: You would like to know what repositories used for installing packages by groupinstall?

Comment: That would be a separate question.  I'd be interested in learning that as well but it is currently not the primary interest here.  I want to know which repository is providing the comps.xml data (namely-- if parsing repomd.xml, the 'group' data).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an option to print group list and the corresponding source repository. Using `-v` option with `groupinfo` lists the source repository for packages from the given group.

```
# yum groupinfo <grp_name> -v
```

or

```
# yum groups info <grp_name> -v # on RHEL 7
Group: Security Tools
Group-Id: security-tools
rpmdb time: 0.000
Description: Security tools for integrity and trust verification.
Default Packages:
  +scap-security-guide-0.1.33-6.el7_4.noarch    rhel-7-server-rpms
Optional Packages:
  aide-0.15.1-13.el7.x86_64                     rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think groups a defined in the metadata of the "base" repo. At least that's what I see in CentOS. They aren't "in" any repo like a package is; rather they're part of the structure of the repo. Here's the only place I see them defined in the CentOS-* repos.

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/*.comps.xml
```

I see another *comps.xml in ELREPO's repodata dir. I think maybe its groups are merged with ones existing in Centos-base and if there aren't existing groups yet, we'll see new groups available.

So, the effect would be that the "base" group gets a few more packages when elrepo is enabled. And there are few new groups.